# If the product of two twin primes is $16926Z8244483$, find $Z$.

Tags: number-theory

> The $13$-digit base-$10$ number $16926Z8244483$ is the product of a pair of twin primes. The sixth digit of this number is represented by the letter $Z$. Find $Z$.

This question is supposed to be solvable in under $5$ minutes without a calculator or computer. I would try looking for perfect squares near $16926Z8244483$, but it can be hard to test if a $6$-digit number is prime.

Answer (score 6):

Clearly none of the two primes are divided by 3. Therefore one is of form $3k-1$, and the second $3k+1$, for some integer $k$. So their product is $9k^2-1$. Thus the remainder is 8 after dividing this product by 9. We know that the sum of digits in a number gives the same remainder as the original number, so now you can easily compute the value of $Z$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The perfect square which is $1$ more than $p(p+2)$ is divisible by $9$.  Now apply the "digit sum" criterion.